How to disable smoothing in fullscreen? (AS3)
Just as the title says. When putting the swf in fullscreen it smooths the graphics (not sure what method it is using, perhaps anti-aliasing?) and I can not find anything online that is in any way close to relevant to this. I find it kind of silly that there would not be a way to disable it so I am sure there is a way.

I don't remember if stage can be resized anyhow, and at fullscreen the app gets stretched directly. Flash engine was explicitly designed for embedded objects which have strict dimensions, so you pretty much can't disable this, however you might try (somehow) catching fullscreen dimensions then resizing the stage to match, then that stretching would go with 1.0 coefficient and be effectively disabled.

Apparently you want stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; possible values are here and the default looks like "exact fit" mode. However, this would make your display a lot smaller after going fullscreen.
